# Teradata SQL - Date format/transformation

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have this table:

```
Original_Date  Date_        Date_1      YearMonth  YearMonth_1
03-07-2020     2020-07-03   2020-06-03  03-0       2020
13-03-2020     2020-03-13   2020-02-13  13-0       2020
08-01-2020     2020-01-08   2019-12-08  08-0       2019
13-11-2020     2020-11-13   2020-10-13  13-1       2020
23-03-2020     2020-03-23   2020-02-23  23-0       2020
30-07-2020     2020-07-30   2020-06-30  30-0       2020
13-07-2020     2020-07-13   2020-06-13  13-0       2020
24-01-2020     2020-01-24   2019-12-24  24-0       2019
05-10-2020     2020-10-05   2020-09-05  05-1       2020
11-07-2020     2020-07-11   2020-06-11  11-0       2020
```

Where if I use `TYPE()` function on them they return:

```
Original Date: VARCHAR
Date_: DATE
Date_1: DATE
YearMonth_1: VARCHAR
YearMonth: VARCHAR
```

These columns are built based on `Original_Date` column, where:

```
SELECT
Original_Date
CAST(Original_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS Date_, -- This is in a subquery, put for simplicity I put it here
ADD_MONTHS(CAST(Original_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY'),-1) AS Date_1, -- This is in a subquery, put for simplicity I put it here
LEFT(CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth,
LEFT(CAST(Date_1 AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth_1,
FROM TABLE
```

The problem is:

- I can't understand why `YearMonth` takes the last (right) four characters instead of the first (left) four characters.
- I was looking for a `YearMonth` with type `DATE` and format like `YYYY-MM`. But as I didn't find any solution with Teradata (if you can provide one, it will be better than the workaround I'm doing now), I'm going for `YYYYMM as integer`, but as you can see when I'm applying `LEFT()` function it seem to work like a `RIGHT()` function, even when both (`Date_` and `Date_1`) have the same data types. why? How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

```
SELECT     
LEFT(CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth_v2,
LEFT(CAST(Date_1 AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth_1_v2,
FROM TABLE
```

Results in:

```
YearMonth_v2  YearMonth_1_v2
03-07-2020    2020-06-03
13-03-2020    2020-02-13
08-01-2020    2019-12-08
13-11-2020    2020-10-13
23-03-2020    2020-02-23
30-07-2020    2020-06-30
13-07-2020    2020-06-13
24-01-2020    2019-12-24
05-10-2020    2020-09-05
11-07-2020    2020-06-11
```

Why transforming the data type of these columns behave differently even when both of them (`Date` and `Date_1`) have the same data type and date format?

Comment: As for your first point, `SELECT CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10))` will probably help you to visualize whats happening.

Comment: It is obviously because you didn't specify the date format. Since you see the date as `dd-MM-yyyy` it worth to assume that `cast` returns the date in the same format and you substring from this string. How the DBMS can know you need a year with substring after you turn it into `VARCHAR`?

Comment: @HoneyBadger I put the example recently.

Comment: @Chris Does it really return 10 characters from `LEFT(..., 4)`?

Comment: @astentx it's not. As you can see, it's returning only four characters. I transformed to varchar(10) before as I don't know how Teradata will cut the date specifically when you specify a varchar with a length less than the length of the date characters

Comment: Check [this docs article](https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/_WAvgD2iMJtE9l~GlnyWOA): *You can use nested CASTs and a FORMAT to do this as demonstrated by the example that follows.*

   `SELECT
   CAST( (CAST (F1 AS FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS CHAR(10))
   FROM INTDAT;`.Since I have no Teradata access I cannot test it and post as answer or check the difference in dates at DBMS level.

Comment: @Chris "I don't know how Teradata will cut the date specifically when you specify a varchar with a length less than the length of the date characters". But that's exactly what you are doing now!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to format a date/timestamp, the easiest way is TO_CHAR plus a format, e.g.

```
TO_CHAR(date_col, 'YYYY-MM') AS YearMonth
```

To get a `YYYYMM` integer:

```
  Extract(YEAR From date_col) * 100 
+ Extract(MONTH From date_col)
```

Comment: Adding that `TO_CHAR()` to my mental library. That is so much nicer than CAST(CAST(CAST)))

Answer (score 1):

The big miss here is that you are fighting nature, or rather then nature of date storage and formatting in Teradata. If you run, as an example, the following:

```
SELECT
  '03-07-2020' AS Original_Date,
  CAST(Original_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS Date_, -- This is in a subquery, put for simplicity I put it here
  ADD_MONTHS(CAST(Original_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY'),-1) Date_1, -- This is in a subquery, put for simplicity I put it here
  CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10)),
  CAST(Date_1 AS varchar(10)),
  LEFT(CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth,
  LEFT(CAST(Date_1 AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth_1


+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| "Original_Date" |  "Date_"   |  "Date_1"  |   "Date_"    |   "Date_1"   | "YearMonth" | "YearMonth_1" |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| "03-07-2020"    | 2020-07-03 | 2020-06-03 | "03-07-2020" | "2020-06-03" | "03-0"      | "2020"        |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

You'll notice that the return of the `ADD_MONTHS()` function is a date formatted in the Teradata default of `YYYY-MM-DD`. This is why your attempt to use the `LEFT()` string function against both of these dates is yielding strange results.

To correct you can just flip that first `YearMonth` to use the `RIGHT()` function instead of `LEFT` or you can re-cast the date format of your `DATE_` like:

```
SELECT
  '03-07-2020' AS Original_Date,
  CAST(CAST(Original_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM_YYYY') AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Date_, -- This is in a subquery, put for simplicity I put it here
  ADD_MONTHS(CAST(Original_Date AS DATE FORMAT 'DD-MM-YYYY'),-1) Date_1, -- This is in a subquery, put for simplicity I put it here
  CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10)),
  CAST(Date_1 AS varchar(10)),
  LEFT(CAST(Date_ AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth,
  LEFT(CAST(Date_1 AS varchar(10)),4) AS YearMonth_1


+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| "Original_Date" |  "Date_"   |  "Date_1"  |   "Date_"    |   "Date_1"   | "YearMonth" | "YearMonth_1" |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| "03-07-2020"    | 2020-07-03 | 2020-06-03 | "2020-07-03" | "2020-06-03" | "2020"      | "2020"        |
+-----------------+------------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
```

The take-away here is that in Teradata if you want to change the format of the date, you MUST use a cast statement so sometimes you'll find yourself casting multiple times, plus Teradata has the tendency to gravitate to the default 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I've found it best to just go with the default so there are no surprises.

Comment: Excellent response.  My TLDR - always specify a format when casting to and from dates.

Comment: Totally on the TLDR. You'll see often times when you want to output in your result set a date in a particular format you get into multiple casts to pull it off (since a cast is needed to change formats): `CAST(CAST(myActualDate as DATE FORMAT 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS VARCHAR(10)) as myStringDate` Which feels strange since it was already a date to begin with. It's also worth noting that instead of your string functions. Something like `CAST(CAST(DATE_ AS DATE FORMAT 'MMYYYY') AS CHAR(6)) AS YearMonth` will work well too.

Answer (score 0):

Simple rules:

- `FORMAT` clauses are only applied when converting some other data type to character string or vice versa. (This could be an explicit `CAST`, or an implicit conversion triggered by applying a function that only operates on strings to a different data type.)
- Applying a `FORMAT` to something does not change how the value is stored.
- When retrieving a value with a data type other than character string, the client is responsible for any formatting performed; the database `FORMAT` clause will be ignored. (In other words, if you want the database to format the data, you need something in your SQL that forces conversion to character string.)

Comment: Aside: By default BTEQ uses the native CLIv2 "field mode" which in effect asks the database to convert all values to character (thereby applying the `FORMAT`). Other utilities and standard drivers (ODBC, JDBC, Python, etc.) do not.

Comment: *you need something in your SQL that forces conversion to character string*: `TO_CHAR` rulez :-)